# logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[32,1] labels_size=[16,1]

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to learn tensorflow and I'm getting the following error: 
logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[32,1] labels_size=[16,1]

The code runs fine when I got this as input:

```
self.input = np.ones((500, 784))
self.y = np.ones((500, 1))
```

However, when I add and extra dimension the error is thrown:

```
self.input = np.ones((500, 2, 784))
    self.y = np.ones((500, 1))
```

The code to build the graph

```
    self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None] + self.config.state_size)
    self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])

    # network architecture
    d1 = tf.layers.dense(self.x, 512, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="dense1")
    d2 = tf.layers.dense(d1, 1, name="dense2")


    with tf.name_scope("loss"):
        self.cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=self.y, logits=d2))
        self.train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.config.learning_rate).minimize(self.cross_entropy,
                                                                                     global_step=self.global_step_tensor)
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(d2, 1), tf.argmax(self.y, 1))
        self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
```

Could someone explain me why this is happening and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`logits` is the name typically given to the output of the network, these are your predictions. A size of `[32, 10]` tells me that you have a batch size of 32, and 10 outputs, such as is common with mnist, as you appear to be working with.

Your labels are sized `[16, 10]`, which is to say, you're providing 16 labels/vectors of size 10. The number of labels you're providing is in conflict with the output of the network, they should be the same.

I'm not quite clear what you're doing with the extra dimension in the input, but I guess you must be accidentally doubling the samples in some way. Perhaps the `[500, 2, 784]` shape is being reshaped to `[1000, 784]` automatically somewhere along the way, which is then not matching the 500 labels. Also, your `self.y` should be shaped `[500, 10]` not, `[500, 1]`, your labels need to be in one-hot encoding format. E.g. a single label of shape `[1, 10]` for digit 3 would be `[[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]`, not in digit representation, e.g. `[3]` as you seem to have it set up in your sanity-test here.

Comment: I'm having the same error here it says logits_size = [288,10] and labels_size = [32,1]  
batch_size is equal to 32 so according to your explanation logits_size should be [32,10] I don't know where 288 came from 
can you please explain it a little bit more

Comment: 32 is assuming a batch size of 32. Your 288 number doesn't fit in there. It looks like something is misshaped on the last layer and loss of your network. I suggest you post a separate question describing the error you get and show the code, at least the last layer and output, and what the shape of the input you are feeding the network.

Comment: I managed to fix that error yet am getting a very high loss value so I think you're right, somewhere there is an issue, probably in the last layer 
my input share is (128,128,3)

Comment: Beautiful Explanation!Thank you!